# Why async task not able to read shared preferences

Tags: android, android-asynctask

Yes , i can pass the values from parent class to the asynctask ,but i am just fiddling with AsyncTask , it cannot read the shared preferences,it is reading the null  .. yes i googled it and found it on another thread of the stackoverflow ,that to put those shared preferences in the onPreexecute ,i have done that .. but of no use 
here is my code

```
 public class Destination extends Activity {

EditText destinationPoint;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_destination);
    destinationPoint=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.dest);
    Parse.initialize(this, "PyCnNKLWz4XAJAroDgLYy7GEi", "nDOBi74l8eGbGXQKBsteGLIkHKEnHkpAVMQ");

}

public void ridenow(View view){
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences =getSharedPreferences("AutoRaja",Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor edit=sharedPreferences.edit();
    edit.putString("destination", destinationPoint.getText().toString());
    edit.commit();
    String name=sharedPreferences.getString("customerName", "jj");
    Log.d("name",name);
    String phoneNumber=sharedPreferences.getString("customerNumber", "900");
    Log.d("phone",phoneNumber);
    String pickup=sharedPreferences.getString("pick", null);
    Log.d("pickup",pickup);
    String destination=sharedPreferences.getString("destination", null);
    Log.d("destination",destination);
    // sending to parse
    ParseObject ob=new ParseObject("Customer");
    ob.put("Name",name);
    ob.put("phone", phoneNumber);
    ob.put("pickup", pickup);
    ob.put("destination", destination);
    ob.saveInBackground();
    Intent i=new Intent(this,Confirmation.class);
    AsyncTaskRunner asyncTaskRunner=new AsyncTaskRunner();
    asyncTaskRunner.execute();
    startActivity(i);
    finish();



}




@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.destination, menu);
    return true;
}


private class AsyncTaskRunner extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,Void>{

    String customername;
    String pickup;
    String destination;
    String message;
    @Override
     protected void onPreExecute() {
          super.onPreExecute();
          SharedPreferences sharedPreferences=getSharedPreferences("Autoraja",Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
         customername=sharedPreferences.getString("customerName", null);
         pickup=sharedPreferences.getString("pick", null);
        destination=sharedPreferences.getString("destination", null);
         message="hi "+customername+", you have successfully booked Auto from "+pickup+" to "+destination +"" ; 

       }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {



        String authkey = "5rBdfU2BhE53008ff8";
        //Multiple mobiles numbers seperated by comma
        String mobiles = "9788506486";
        //Sender ID,While using route4 sender id should be 6 characters long.
        String senderId = "AutoRJ";
        //Your message to send, Add URL endcoding here.

        //define route
        String route="4";

        //Prepare Url
        URLConnection myURLConnection=null;
        URL myURL=null;
        BufferedReader reader=null;

        //encoding message 
        String encoded_message=URLEncoder.encode(message);

        //Send SMS API
        String mainUrl="https://control.msg91.com/sendhttp.php?";

        String url;
        //Prepare parameter string 
        StringBuilder sbPostData= new StringBuilder();  
        sbPostData.append("authkey="+authkey); 
        sbPostData.append("&mobiles="+mobiles);
        sbPostData.append("&message="+encoded_message);
        sbPostData.append("&route="+route);
        sbPostData.append("&sender="+senderId);

        //final string
        mainUrl += sbPostData.toString();
        try
        {
            //prepare connection
            myURL = new URL(mainUrl);
            myURLConnection = myURL.openConnection();
            myURLConnection.connect();
            reader= new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(myURLConnection.getInputStream()));
            //reading response 
            String response;
            while ((response = reader.readLine()) != null) 
            //print response 
            System.out.println(response);

            //finally close connection
            reader.close();
        } 
        catch (IOException e) 
        { 
            e.printStackTrace();
        } 

        return null;
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
}

}
```

EDIT: I have used the wrong name of shared preferences , but this question may be useful for those , who cannot access shared prefs from async task ,doInBackground method

Comment: Please try to give proper problem descriptions. I have no idea what you are asking...

Comment: "Autoraja" != "AutoRaja"

Comment: define your pref name as static final. private **static final PREF_NAME="AutoRaja";** And use this

Comment: thanks , as soon as my question made sense ,you reversed your downvote @XaverKapeller

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
getSharedPreferences("Autoraja",Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
```

versus

```
getSharedPreferences("AutoRaja",Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
```

Find the difference:)

Comment: may i ask ,how did you find it ?

Comment: Its a common problem, that was the first thing I checked.

Comment: anyways thanks ,another doubt i cannot access SPs in doInBackground right ?

Comment: You should use a constant instead of typing the name of the preference every time. For example: public static final String PREF_NAME = "AutoRaja";

Comment: You can access SP in doInBackground.